# $T=\{\{x\}:x \in X\}$ Find $σ(Τ)$ where $X$ is a set and $σ(Τ)$ is the intersection of all σ-Algebras containing $T$

Tags: measure-theory

$T \subseteq X$ is a set and $σ(Τ)$ is the intersection of all σ-Algebras containing $T$ (or simpler the smallest σ-Algebra containing T).
What I've tried so far is find a  set $A$ so that $A \subseteq σ(Τ)\subseteq A$. But I have no intuitional ideas about this $A$ set, let alone a solution to the problem.

Comment: It is a standard example the sigma algebra of the the numerable and co-numerable sets:
$$\Sigma = \{A\subseteq X:|A|=|\mathbb{N}|\text{ or }|X\backslash A|=|\mathbb{N}|\}$$

Comment: @VeridianDynamics Thank you that's helpful I made the proof generalizing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show $\sigma(Τ)\subseteq \mathcal{A}$, it is enough to show that $T\subseteq \mathcal{A}$, if you already found that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra (because $\sigma(Τ)$ is the smallest one containing all elements of $T$).

Now try out the *countable-cocountable $\sigma$-algebra* $\mathcal{A}=\{S\subseteq X\ |\ \text{$S$ is countable or $X\backslash S$ is countable}\}$. This should be a clear choice, as you need all countable unions $\bigcup_{x\in T}\{x\}$ (and their complements) to be in $\mathcal{A}$.

Now $T\subseteq \mathcal{A}$ is trivial.

And $\mathcal{A}\subseteq \sigma(Τ)$ is obvious too, as $S$ or $X\backslash S$ can then be written as a countable union of elements of $T$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take $A=\{numerable\ set\} \cup \{co-numerable \ set\} $ is a σ-Algebra,

- then $σ(Τ) \subseteq A$
- We can also see that $\{numerable\ set\}\subseteq σ(Τ)$ and $\{co{-}numerable\ set\}\subseteq σ(Τ)$. That means that $A=\{numerable\ set\} \cup \{co-numerable \ set\}\subseteq σ(Τ) $

$A\subseteq σ(Τ) \subseteq A$ so $A=σ(T)$